# Is it possible to use jetpack compose in a flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to integrate `jetpack compose` inside my `flutter` application. To easily add all the dependencies required for compose I created a new compose activity which automatically added all the required files in my gradle but when I run the app I get error saying

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{46c6aaa VFE...... ......ID 0,0-720,1424 #1}
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:349)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareWindowRecomposer$default(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:324)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:168)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:224)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:299)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.resolveParentCompositionContext(ComposeView.android.kt:242)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:249)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:286)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:197)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:197)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:197)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:197)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1278)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:4536)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:3228)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3533)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2919)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:10491)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1108)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:866)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:797)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
2023-05-09 13:58:32.798  1232-1232  AndroidRuntime          com.example.flutappthree             E      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
    2023-05-09 13:58:33.339  1614-1935  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{f86b6af u0 Splash Screen com.example.flutappthree EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5871 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5852 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5992 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord$$ExternalSyntheticLambda13.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onAnimationFinished:7947 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.postApplyAnimation:5602 
    ---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (1232) for package com.example.flutappthree ----------------------------
```

My gradle file is as follows

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutappthree"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.6'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.0'
}
```

I am using kotlin 1.8.0. If I comment out the compose code it works fine.

Below is my code

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        flutterEngine
            .platformViewsController
            .registry
            .registerViewFactory("myComposeView", MyComposeViewFactory())

    }
}

class MyComposeViewFactory : PlatformViewFactory(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE) {
    override fun create(context: Context, viewId: Int, args: Any?): PlatformView {
        val creationParams = args as Map<String?, Any?>?
        return MyComposeView(context, viewId, creationParams)
    }
}

class MyComposeView(context: Context, id: Int, creationParams: Map<String?, Any?>?) : PlatformView {

    private val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout
    private val textView: TextView
    private val composeView: ComposeView

    override fun getView(): View {
        return constraintLayout
    }

    init {
        constraintLayout = ConstraintLayout(context)
        textView = TextView(context)
        composeView = ComposeView(context)



        val layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        constraintLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams

        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)

        textView.id = View.generateViewId();
        composeView.id = View.generateViewId();
        constraintLayout.addView(textView)
        constraintLayout.addView(composeView)

        textView.text = "Hello from xml"
        textView.textSize = 30f
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)

        constraintSet.constrainWidth(textView.id,ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
        constraintSet.constrainHeight(textView.id,ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
        constraintSet.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT);
        constraintSet.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
        constraintSet.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP);
        constraintSet.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)


        composeView.setContent {
            MyComposeText()
        }
    }

    override fun dispose() {}
}

@Composable
fun MyComposeText() {
    Text(text = "Hello from compose", style = TextStyle(color = Color.Red, fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to integrate jetpack compose in flutter. They both are UI frameworks. They both have the same function. If you want to use jetpack compose, why even use flutter in the first place?

Comment: I think yes, you can use **platform channels** to open Android Activity that use Jetpack compose

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672894/open-android-activity-and-ios-viewcontroller-from-flutter

Comment: @AyoubBoumzebra That's what I am using

Comment: @Ivo Flutter promises that we can use native views in a flutter app. I don't see why not I can use compose & flutter together

Comment: Maybe the problem here is that Compose requires `AppCompatActivity` to be used, and `FlutterActivity` is subclass of `Activity`

Comment: @PhilDukhov Thanks to you I was able to figure it out. I had to use FlutterFragmentActivity. AppCompatActivity is not directly supported as I need to override configureFlutterEngine which is not present in AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Phil Dukhov I was able to figure it out, all I had to do was to use `FlutterFragmentActivity` instead of `FlutterActivity`

Answer (score 0):

As per BraveEvidence's answer, switching to `FlutterFragmentActivity` should resolve the issue for platform views implemented via `FlutterActivity`. However, if using `FlutterPlugin` instead, this issue will still persist as there is no means to switch to a fragment for view handling. Ultimately you will need to "trick" the activities `decorView` into believing lifecycle owners are attached. This can be done using the following `ProxyLifeCycleOwner` and the `onCreate()` and `attachToDecorView` functions.

```
internal class ProxyLifeCycleOwner :
    LifecycleOwner, ViewModelStoreOwner, SavedStateRegistryOwner {

    fun onCreate() {
        performRestore()
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    }

    fun onResume() {
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    }

    fun onPause() {
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    }

    fun onDestroy() {
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        store.clear()
    }

    fun performRestore(savedState: Bundle? = null) {
        savedStateRegistryController.performRestore(savedState)
    }

    /**
    Compose uses the Window's decor view to locate the
    Lifecycle/ViewModel/SavedStateRegistry owners.
    Therefore, we need to set this class as the "owner" for the decor view.
     */
    fun attachToDecorView(decorView: View?) {
        if (decorView == null) return

        decorView.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(this)
        decorView.setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(this)
        decorView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(this)
    }

    // LifecycleOwner methods
    private val lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)
    override val lifecycle: Lifecycle
        get() = lifecycleRegistry

    // ViewModelStore methods
    private val store = ViewModelStore()
    override val viewModelStore: ViewModelStore
        get() = store

    // SavedStateRegistry methods
    private val savedStateRegistryController = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)
    override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry
        get() = savedStateRegistryController.savedStateRegistry
}
```

Due to the way in which the `FlutterView` inherits these properties from `decorView` during registry and view creation, I recommend attaching the proxy lifecycle to `decorView` in the `onFlutterViewAttached` override of `PlatformView` in the NativeView class returned by your ViewFactory

```
override fun onFlutterViewAttached(flutterView: View) {
    // Trick The ComposeView into believing we are tracking lifecycle
    lifecycleOwner.onCreate()
    lifecycleOwner.attachToDecorView(view.rootView as View)
    super.onFlutterViewAttached(flutterView)
}
```