# Is it possible to use Jetpack Compose within Flutter by utilizing platform views?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mobile-development

I encountered an issue while integrating Android Jetpack Compose into Flutter using the platform view provided by Flutter.

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setContent(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V in class Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView' appears in /data/app/~~jNPuLsqJ5chFROaeevr0TQ==/com.example.example-_A0JqLOSwN-L0KrftRNktw==/base.apk)**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory


class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {

override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

    flutterEngine
        .platformViewsController
        .registry
        .registerViewFactory("flutter_native_example", MyComposeViewFactory())

     }
    }

 
class MyComposeViewFactory : 
PlatformViewFactory(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE) {
override fun create(context: Context, viewId: Int, args: Any?): 
PlatformView {
    val creationParams = args as Map<String?, Any?>?
    return MyComposeView(context, viewId, creationParams)
}
}


class MyComposeView(context: Context, id: Int, creationParams: Map<String?, Any?>?) : PlatformView {

private val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout
private val textView: TextView
private val composeView: ComposeView

override fun getView(): View {
    return constraintLayout
}

init {
    constraintLayout = ConstraintLayout(context)
    textView = TextView(context)
    composeView = ComposeView(context)



    val layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    constraintLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams

    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)

    textView.id = View.generateViewId();
    composeView.id = View.generateViewId();
    constraintLayout.addView(textView)
    constraintLayout.addView(composeView)

    textView.text = "Hello from xml"
    textView.textSize = 30f
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)

    constraintSet.constrainWidth(textView.id,ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
    constraintSet.constrainHeight(textView.id,ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
    constraintSet.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    constraintSet.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    constraintSet.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP);
    constraintSet.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)


    composeView.setContent {
        MyComposeText()
    }
}

override fun dispose() {}
}





@Composable
fun MyComposeText() {
 Text(text = "Hello from compose")
}
```

already added in build.gradle

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
}
```

Initially, I encountered an error **java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found.** I found a solution in this question: [stackoverflow.com link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76207369/is-it-possible-to-use-jetpack-compose-in-a-flutter-application/77738819#77738819). However, when I ran the app again, I still got the same error. Thinking it might have been my mistake, I copied the code from the mentioned question's link, but the error persisted.

**My use case:**
I have a use case in my app to display an overlay when a new order arrives at a restaurant. This alert needs to be shown in front of any other app, even when the main app is terminated. I have already developed this functionality using a pub package from pub.dev. Upon inspecting the package's code, I made modifications to tailor it to my specific requirements. The package's source code is already written in Android XML, but I plan to create another plugin for internal use. I intend to develop this using Android Jetpack without utilizing XML, allowing for design changes from Flutter through argument passing via method channels.

Comment: I had the same issue, but I resolved it by add buildFeatures and composeOptions to my app/build.gradle, and including the androidx.compose.ui:ui dependency, which I assume you've done.

Maybe it's the low kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion? I have it on 1.5.1

Comment: For reference I'm not actually writing the Compose code in my app. It comes from an SDK that exposes an AbstractComposeView. I add that directly to my layout, without the need for a ComposeView.